# Hold off React Render Until Firebase RTDB Shard Initialized

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using RTDB shards.  I have one default shard that contains data about which shard a user should connect to.

When the page loads, I run initializeApp to connect to the default shard.  Then I create an onAuthStateChanged listener to get user data.  Once I have the user data I look up which shard the user should connect to in the default shard.  Then, I run initializeApp for the user's shard.

However, React begins rendering before the initialize default shard -> onAuthStateChanged -> look up shard for user -> initialize user's shard cycle is complete.

It produces this error:

> Firebase: No Firebase App 'shard' has been created - call Firebase
> App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

Which makes sense, I'm just not sure of a clean way to fix it.

Here is where I initialize the app/shard

```
let app;
if (getApps().length === 0) {
  // Initialize Firebase app
  app = initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
  });
} else {
  // Use existing app if already initialized
  app = getApp();
}

// Once we have a user, connect to the corresponding DB Shard
const auth = getAuth(app);
onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
  if (user) {
    try {
      let databaseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL;
      const slugifiedEmail = user.email.replace('@', '_AT_').replace('.', '_DOT_');

      const overrideSnap = await get(ref(getDatabase(app), `/shards/userOverrides/${slugifiedEmail}`));
      if (overrideSnap.val()) {
        databaseURL = `https://${overrideSnap.val().shard}.firebaseio.com`
      } else {
        const domainSnap = await get(ref(
          getDatabase(app),
          `/shards/domains/${user.email.replace(/.*@/, "").replace('.', '_DOT_')}`
        ));

        databaseURL = `https://${domainSnap.val().shard}.firebaseio.com`
      }

      initializeApp({
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
        databaseURL,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
        measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
      }, 'shard')
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error when connecting to shard', e)
    }
  }
});
```

This is how I'm using it in my component

```
function DashboardSection(props) {
  const [demoDBVal, setDemoDBVal] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('getApps', getApps())
    get(ref(getDatabase(getApp('shard')), `/`)).then(snap => {
      setDemoDBVal(snap.val())
    })
  })

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(demoDBVal)}</div>

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you show wait with rendering a component until the shard is initialized. Instead of describing your code, can you show the actual [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yeah I agree but I don't know how to detect if the shard has been initialized other than a setInterval checking to see if it is there or not.  Code added

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. Isn't right after `initializeApp({ ... }, 'shard')`, where you know you can start rendering the component that depends on the `shard` app instance. You could even put the app itself in the state.